# Editing a TextInput in a ScrollView

Tags: qt, scrollview, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I have an issue with my QML. I'd like to edit a `TextInput` based on an action, setting the `focus` attribute to `true`. It works when the `TextInput` is located in a `Rectangle`, but not in a `ScrollView`.
Here is an example:

```
Item {
    id: main
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ScrollView{
        id: scrollView
        height: parent.height/2
        width: parent.width

        Rectangle{
            border.color: "black"
            border.width: 1
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            height: 25
            width: 200
            TextInput{
                id: ti1
                anchors.fill: parent
                verticalAlignment: TextInput.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter
            }
        }

    }

    Rectangle{
        y: height
        height: parent.height/2
        width: parent.width

        Rectangle{
            border.color: "black"
            border.width: 1
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            height: 25
            width: 200
            TextInput{
                id: ti2
                anchors.fill: parent
                verticalAlignment: TextInput.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            if (mouseY < parent.height/2){
                ti2.focus = false
                ti1.focus = true
            }else{
                ti1.focus = false
                ti2.focus = true
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I click on the bottom half of the window, the `TextInput` ti2 is editable. But when I click on the top half, ti1 is not.

Does anybody have any idea? The behaviour is the same with `TextEdit`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is because:
*"Only one Item can be a direct child of the ScrollView and the child is implicitly anchored to fill the scroll view."*.

From: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-scrollview.html

Perhaps the tree of components is unavailable in a ScrollView.

But if you use:

```
ti1.forceActiveFocus();
```

instead of:

```
ti1.focus = true
```

it works.